# How to assign the average and print as an integer

Tags: python

The instructions are to assign avg_owls with the average owls per zoo. Print avg_owls as an integer. However, the math keeps coming up wrong with the sample inputs. Even when I do the math by hand. The code is as follows.

Given sample inputs are 1 2 4

```
avg_owls = 0.0

num_owls_zooA = int(input())
num_owls_zooB = int(input())
num_owls_zooC = int(input())

avg_owls = int(num_owls_zooA + num_owls_zooB + num_owls_zooC / 3)

print('Average owls per zoo:', int(avg_owls))
```

Your output
Average owls per zoo: 4
Expected output
Average owls per zoo: 2

I have written and can only alter the code avg_owls = int(num_owls_zooA + num_owls_zooB + num_owls_zooC / 3)

I don't understand how it's coming up with 4 when the actual math comes out to 2.333

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Btw, you don't need to convert `avg_owls` to `int`, just pass it to print as it is..

Comment: Thank you. They're giving me a lot of information to take in. I don't know how they expect me to remember it all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Operator precedence, and the rules of maths, say that

```
num_owls_zooA + num_owls_zooB + num_owls_zooC / 3
```

will be calculated as

```
num_owls_zooA + num_owls_zooB + (num_owls_zooC / 3)
```

You need some brackets to get the result you want:

```
(num_owls_zooA + num_owls_zooB + num_owls_zooC) / 3
```

As an extra note, applying `int` to the result feels potentially wrong. It will cause it to always round down. For an average you would usually want to either keep it as a floating point value or at least round to the nearest value rather than always down.

Comment: Thanks! Math isn't my strongest suit. This is for a class.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems here. In pemdas or germdas, division comes before addition. SO you need parentheses around the addition. Also if you do `int(4.3)` you will get `4`. float will give you your desired output

```
avg_owls = 0.0

num_owls_zooA = float(input())
num_owls_zooB = float(input())
num_owls_zooC = float(input())

avg_owls = (num_owls_zooA + num_owls_zooB + num_owls_zooC) / 3

print(f'Average owls per zoo: {avg_owls} ')
```

also I suggest using `f strings`.

Comment: You don't need to initialize `avg_owls`. Also it's better to stay with `int` while object of count is an owl, could you imagine three and half owls? :D

Comment: Thank you. I'm stressed out. this is all new to me and I'm not the greatest at math either.

Comment: @OlvinRoght Don't worry. I thought about it all. My memory from my owl cutting past is coming back. I think I remember seeing a 1/16 nth of an owl.

Comment: @BuddyBob, tough times

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```py
avg_owls = int((num_owls_zooA + num_owls_zooB + num_owls_zooC) / 3)
```

This solution works as tested.

Answer (score 0):

This is the right answer...

total_owls = int(num_owls_A) + int(num_owls_B)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

avg_owls = (num_owls_zooA + num_owls_zooB + num_owls_zooC) / 3

num_owls_zooA = int(1)

num_owls_zooB = int(2)

num_owls_zooC = int(4)

That is the solution.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct one:

avg_owls = float((num_owls_zooA + num_owls_zooB + num_owls_zooC) / 3)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).